# Unable to understand the python decorator function

Tags: python, function, decorator

Please note, I don't know what exactly to give subject to this question.

I'm going through a tutorial for creating decorators. The doubt is in the third line. I do not fully understand it.

I know that `count` is not a function. Because, I changed `wrapper.count` to `wrapper.cnt` and the code worked. But when i changed the `wrapper.count` to `wrap.count`, then it errors out.

That means we're referencing the wrapper function from within wrapper function itself. Fine, but what is the associated `.count` really ?

Please explain. Below is the code.

```
def counter(func):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    wrapper.count += 1
    # Call the function being decorated and return the result
    func()
    return wrapper.count
  wrapper.count = 0
  # Return the new decorated function
  return wrapper

# Decorate foo() with the counter() decorator
@counter
def foo():
  print('calling foo()')

foo()
foo()

print('foo() was called {} times.'.format(foo.count))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python treat functions as objects, which means that you can assign values to functions dynamically.

```
def hello():
    print(hello.some_variable)

hello.some_variable = 'Hello!'
hello()  # Prints 'Hello!'

hello.some_variable = 'Goodbye!'
hello()  # Prints 'Goodbye!'
```

So what's happening is that the decorator is assigning the variable `count` to the wrapped function (in this case `foo`). Then it access and increments this variable from `foo`, which you then print.

Answer (score 0):

```
wrapper.count = 0
```

`wrapper.count` is an `int`.  It starts with the value 0 and increments each time you say `wrapper.count += 1`.